# transpose key value data from a dataframe to a column based on keys in python

Tags: python, dataframe, key-value

I have the input from a website in the XML format and I was able to get it into a dataframe in the format below ,
can you help me as to how can I write a python code to convert the data into the output expected, shown below.

Data in Dataframe

```
    pDate                          | pname             |meta_key     |meta_value
0   Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000|2021-07-17-67433-43|access_code  |67433
1   Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000|2021-07-17-67433-43|email        |xxx@dddd.com
2   Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000|2021-07-17-67433-43|activity_id  |43
3   Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000|2021-07-17-67433-43|duration_step|50
4   Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000|2021-07-17-67433-43|type         |M
5   Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000|2021-07-17-67433-43|multiplier   |122
6   Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000|2021-07-17-67433-43|date         |2021-07-17
7   Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000|2021-07-17-13254-42|access_code  |13254
8   Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000|2021-07-17-13254-42|email        |xxxx@ccc.com
9   Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000|2021-07-17-13254-42|activity_id  |42
```

Expected Output in a dataframe to be usable for charts

```
pDate                          | name               | access_code | email       | activity_id | duration_step | type | multiplier |date | 
Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000|2021-07-17-67433-43 | 67433       |xxx@dddd.com |43           |50             |    M |. 122.      | 2021-07-17
```

Comment: In the expected output, do you need the two `.` around the value in the `multiplier` column?

Comment: Nope, treat as a typo ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.pivot`:

```py
print(
    df.pivot(index=["pDate", "pname"], columns="meta_key", values="meta_value")
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis("", axis=1)
)
```

Prints:

```
                             pDate                pname access_code activity_id        date duration_step         email multiplier type
0  Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000  2021-07-17-13254-42       13254          42         NaN           NaN  xxxx@ccc.com        NaN  NaN
1  Mon, 19 Jul 2021 06:13:05 +0000  2021-07-17-67433-43       67433          43  2021-07-17            50  xxx@dddd.com        122    M
```

Comment: thanks Andrej, it really solves the problem, I am to transpose the data in groups. This is exact solution.